# using ujson instead of django default json serializer

Tags: json, django, ujson

as you known django uses json library for serializing querysets to json and DjangoJSONEncoder class uses json.JSONEncoder as it's superclass and there is no such class in ujson library.
how can i use ujson instead of json in django serializer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this (using values):

```
some_values = SomeModel.objects.values(
        'pk', 'some_field',
)
```

and serialising it:

```
mark_safe(ujson.dumps(list(some_values), ensure_ascii=False))
```